# Joining a List with a Table in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following Model and populated Data as follows.

```
public class School
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public string Class {get;set;}
 public bool IsActive {get;set;}
}

//After making a service I get the following data with IsActive as false initially.
List<School> schoolList = //make service call
[{1,'A','First',0} , {2,'B','Second',0}].
```

Next I have a `MasterTable` table with columns as `ID,Name,Area` .
Eg:

```
1 A ABC
2 B DEF
3 H GHJ
```

If the data stored in `Name` property in `schoolList` matches with Name in `MasterTable` , then once again I need to update the `IsActive` property of `schoolList` as true .

I tried the following approach.

1. Get all the data from MasterTable using EF Core and extract Name column and store it in a List `NameFromMasterTable` ;
2. Loop schoolList.ForEach() and in the loop, check if Name is present in `NameFromMasterTable` and if found update , IsActive as true.

Since this approach fetches all the data from table and also looping on each and every row and updating is a expensive operation. Whats the best way to update the `IsActive` of `schoolList` to true if Name is found in `MasterTable's` `Name` column?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need at least two loops for this, but the inclusion of a `HashSet<T>` will prevent the O(N^2) time complexity.  If you create a `HashSet<string>` and populate it with the `Name` values from `MasterTable` you can then use this collection as a reference when iterating `schoolList` to set `IsActive`.

The `HashSet<T>.Contains()` method is O(1).  This is all assuming you do not care about the `ID` column in either of the tables, which seems to be the case.

`HashSet<T>` has a constructor that takes `IEqualityComparer<string>` if you need to be concerned with case sensitivity.